# Get Facebook page ID from submitted URL

Tags: php, regex

How do I get a Facebook page ID from submitted URL if the URL can have different formats?

Different URL formats that a page can have:

```
https://www.facebook.com/aftonbladet <- ID = aftonbladet 

https://www.facebook.com/aftonbladet?ref=ts&fref=ts <- ID = aftonbladet

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Se%C3%B1oras-que-pues-soy-SE%C3%91ORA-y-tengo-FACEBOOK/114080805301413 <- ID = 114080805301413
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/(?:[^\/]*\/)*(.*?)(?:$|\?)
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/xZ7jP2/1)

The pattern consumes all text up to the last slash `/`, then captures everything up to the end of the string or the next `?` character.